# Traversing subdirectories & create similar directory structure to process each file in sub directories

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I want to create a batch script to process the directory and files in
that directory, Basically I am using one tool to convert files in
directory to some format and it can take each file separately also can
handle complete directory. Now I want to convert all the files in
directory/sub directory with same directory structure for eg.

```
║
║═════ Folder 1
║         ║
║         ║══════ Folder A
║                     ║
║                     ║═════ File1.adt
║
║═════ Folder 5
          ║
          ║═════ File5.adt
```

Now I want the conversion of above files in same directory structure
but can be at different location.

```
║
║═════ Folder 1
║         ║
║         ║══════ Folder A
║                     ║
║                     ║═════ File1.txt
║
║═════ Folder 5
          ║
          ║═════ File5.txt
```

Comment: Please provide a command line example of the tool involved, and describe what it does.

Comment: As you can see in Command Line below:-C:\Program Files\ABC Amber Advantage Converter\abcadv.exe" "C:\demo.adt" "C:\demo.csv" 0 what this abc advantage converter does is it converts *.adt files to *.csv files or to another formats too , here in above commant i am converting single file , if we give path till directory only it will convert all the files in directory having *.adt extension to *.csv extension, Where 0 is option of conversion type .

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this:

```
@echo off
for /r "c:\adt_folder_root" %%a in (*.adt) do "C:\Program Files\ABC Amber Advantage Converter\abcadv.exe" "%%a" "%%~dpna.csv" 0
```

The /r switch will traverse the folder structure starting from the folder specified.